# Crop Images in android

Tags: android

I wrote these codes to crop an image :

```
Intent data = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
data.setDataAndType(imagePath,"image/*");

List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(data, 0);
int size = list.size();
/**
* If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
*/
if (size == 0) {
    this.finish();
    return;
}

data.putExtra("crop", "true");
data.putExtra("scale", true);
data.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(data, REQUEST_CROP);
```

sometimes it stuck on saving image, if I add these lines it will be right

```
data.putExtra("outputX", ...);
data.putExtra("outputY", ...);
data.putExtra("aspectX",...);
data.putExtra("aspectY", ...);
```

but I don't want to use these because I want to use User's desired size, not mine.
any Idea that what is the problem ? because just for some images it happens.

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: I used Crop apps that is installed on device, before u decrease my votes just read my codes and search and find a lot of results

Comment: do you want to pass cropped image through intent?

Comment: it stcuks on cropping image not on passing image

Comment: what exactly do You mean with "stuck"? Is it crashing or does it just need long time? I think You have a problem with the size of the image.....

Comment: "I used Crop apps that is installed on device" -- there is no requirement for a "crop app" to be on any given device. Please read [the blog post that I linked to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Then, please use [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: "com.android.camera.action.CROP", this intent list all installed app on device and user pick one, Our strategy is this to use installed Crop apps.

Comment: I think something here is not clear enough. As I understand You the wright way, cropping image works. BUT You have some problem by saving the fetched image, aren´t you?

Comment: When I call "startActivityForResult", it list some apps that can crop, then user select one, when he select his desired rect then he touch save button, in that place i hangs not crash, it says please wait but nothing happened

Comment: then I think You should show Your code where You save the image....

Comment: why when I add those lines ( aspectX, outputX,...) it works fine, or why for some images it works for some not, and when I touch save button that application save and send me just the result, I don't save it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can try using other libraries for cropping the image. Eg : See [This](http://square.github.io/picasso)!

Answer (score 0):

I use this library ,

https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView

works great even on Android N and is easy to implement